# devise: set timeout_in dynamically with custom session controller on before/after actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I am trying to create a fast login system for users, and I need that if they activate this option, the sessions will timeouted after 20 seconds.

What I have done is this in a CustomSessionController:

```
class CustomSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :before_login, only: :create, if: :fastlogin?
  after_action :after_login, only: :create, if: :fastlogin?

  def before_login
    user = finduserlogic…
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      user.fastlogin = true
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def after_login
    current_user.fastlogin = false
    current_user.save!
  end

  def fastlogin?
    params[:user][:fastlogin].present?
  end
end
```

So, this sets a fastlogin field to true before login, and after the login back to false.

Then in the User model I override the timeout_in method:

```
def timeout_in
  if self.fastlogin
    20.seconds
  else
    Devise.timeout_in
  end
end
```

The problem is, it seems like fastlogin never turns to true in the user.timeout_in method, but debugging it seems like it changes in before and after hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Devise timeoutable strategy does not play well with variable timeouts: `timeout_in` should be correct at time when session is checked for validity (on each request after login, when you already set `fastlogin` back to `false`), not on creation.

In your case that timeout is a property of a single session, not the user, so you have to keep it in warden session and use for calculations. 
See [hook for timeoutable](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb) to get the idea on how it works.